# How to create Anamorphic, Optical Illusion, 3D Large format print?

Tags: print-design, 3d, photoshop-effects, photo-editing, optical-illusion

Sorry it's a broad question..
I have a project where I am making the inside of a trailer look like it's either the interior of an aeroplane, or its an aeroplane with no roof, so you have visible site of the wings and sky in all directions. I will include an image i found which give some idea of what I'm trying to achieve. [image]

(This isn't my image - copyright to Technicion IXION)

I would like my design to appear as realistic as possible. The trailer I'm wrapping does have curved walls..which suit the airplane idea but It makes things a little more confusing with the perspective... I hope I'm making sense here It's tricky to explain but as you can see in the image i found, the wings appear to be in the correct angle from the current view point. How then would you wrap a slightly curved wall if you were facing the wall so that when you stand back at the view point (like in photo) it appears 3d..

Answer (score 1):

You have 4 options:

1. Construct a 3D model and making a 3D render (with a photorealistic renderer)
2. Construct a 3D model and using it as a basis for a 2D painting or drawing.
3. Use a one point perspective grid a s a basis for a paint or drawing: https://www.google.com.mx/search?q=one+point+perspective+grid
4. Construct a real life scenario and take a picture with an ultra wide lens.

**I would use option 1**. But it is not an easy task, so probably you need to hire someone.

If you are **good at drawing** then use the option 2. Use a 3D program like https://www.blender.org/ or https://www.sketchup.com which are free. You could use to make simple blocks with the correct proportion as a simple reference. There are some free seats that you could download too.

For the option 1. Use Blender. Solid, powerfull, free.

Another good option is Sketchup but it does not have the photorealistic renderer. I used several years ago Kerkythea (http://www.kerkythea.net/cms/), but I am not sure if it is compatible with newer versions of Sketchup.

#### Edited to complement comments

If you use the option 2. Having a perspective as a reference for ilustrator or option 1, making an actual render totally, totally depends on two factors.

a) The style you need

b) Your skill

Typical vector look on a vector program: https://www.google.com/search?q=vector+illustration

Photorealistic render: https://www.google.com/search?q=3D+render

Raytraced render: https://www.google.com/search?q=raytrace+render

Kerkythea renderer gallery: http://www.kerkythea.net/cms/index.php/gallery

An old Blender renderer gallery: http://archive.blender.org/features-gallery/gallery/

Comment: Ok thank you, for option 1 what programme would you use ?

Comment: Hi Rachel I already mentioned it. Blender. I will edit my answer to clarify.

Comment: Ok thanks for your help. not In a position to hire someone, so Im going to have a go myself. I have downloaded both the programmes you mentioned,sketch-up initially looks easier to use, but i'll try both. So, am I correct in saying, you're telling me to use these programmes to create myself a reference tool so I know which perspective/warping will work best? But then I would need to go back to photoshop / illustrator to create my actual design for the printing?