# How to design and print 3d anamorphic images?

Tags: print-design, 3d, photo-editing, print-production, perspective

Here's some photo of what I'm talking about
[image]
the majority I've seen are floor and wall but I need to create this 3d effect on wall and ceiling with an aerial London skyline and clouds. using the image below:
[image]

How do I do this? The desired effect is to feel like your in a glass aeroplane and can see the city around you and clouds overhead.

I have seen a post about changing the perspective on a single image [Anamorphic Design Process](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/49109/anamorphic-design-process/63849#63849)

but how would you morph a landscape photo like the city one i have?

Comment: somehow this feels like a duplicate of this: [how-to-create-anamorphic-optical-illusion-3d-large-format-print](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/75634/how-to-create-anamorphic-optical-illusion-3d-large-format-print)

Comment: No, it is a complete diferent topic.

Comment: @Rafael No its the same problem. The same approach works for both solutions.

Answer (score 1):

### Edited because your comment

I am not sure if you understand what this kind of projection means. This means that there is only one point in the entire surrounding where you can see the effect correctly.

If you start moving around the real place, you see the images distorted.

Take a look at this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tBNHPk-Lnkk

The user posted a download link for the images, so you can print them:

- https://i.stack.imgur.com/NoXPA.jpg , which looks like so:

  [image]
- https://i.stack.imgur.com/FgIrY.jpg , which looks like so:

  [image]

### Original answer

1. Choose a public space.
2. Pray the weather is not rainy.
3. Choose a spot for a camera. That is practically the only point where a scene looks right.
4. Skilfully paint your scene... There is a lot to explain here, out of the scope of the forum.

Painting on a public space is made with chalk, so it can be washed away later.

Take a look at this post: [Anamorphic Design Process](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/49109/anamorphic-design-process/63849#63849)

and this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3SNYtd0Ayt0

Comment: yes its the same project but but I am trying something else, but same question or not, I still don't have the answers i'm looking for... so I will explain some more:

Comment: I'm looking to create this digitally, I will be printing on a large format latex printer onto vinyl which i then will use to wrap the room, But I want to create the anamorphic 3d effect (thats if anamorphic is the right approach, perhaps there is another solution I'm missing.)

Comment: If I can get this right for this interior design project I wish to use the 3d method for wrapping a bus and a trailer...my later projects in the near future.  I have seen the results of 3d artwork on vehicles, or floors, I know its possible doing it digitally I just don't know how?! I could try the stretch method using the grid and just see how it turns out, but i feel like this would apply more to objects as appose to scenes like the sky I want to create. ..I will do some trial and error but meanwhile if you think of something please let me know! Thanks again everyone

Comment: I have the feeling you are NOT seeing the links I posted. I linked you a method to make thoose. Using perspective deformations. You also can simulate the room in a 3D program: http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/49109/anamorphic-design-process/63849#63849

Comment: ok I will try this method out and see what happens, I have seen your links etc and appreciate your help. I'll try out that

Comment: Explore the post with the deformations made with perspective in Photoshop. If you need a more advanced method I will expand some of the two answers with a projection made on blender.